# Jquery mobile duplicando elementos

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Troca Games - Games com economia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="padding:15px; text-align:center">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="100%"/>
    <br/>
    
    <?php 
        if($_GET['access'])
            echo '<div class="login_failed"><h3>Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)</h3></div>'
    ?>
    
    <form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="fm_login" class="login" data-transition="slide">
        <input name="usuario_usu" type="text" placeholder="Usuário"></input>
        <input name="senha_usu" type="password" placeholder="Senha"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="bt_login" value="Entrar"></input>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p style="font-size:20px">Não possui conta? <a href="#">Cadastre-se!</a></p>
    <br>
    <img src="images/login_facebook.jpg" width="100%"/>
    <img src="images/login_google.jpg" width="100%"/>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A sua pergunta está bastante vaga! Quais elementos é que ele está a duplicar? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/91508/edit) e construa melhor a sua pergunta, pois assim como ela está, o mais provável é ela vir a ficar suspensa.

Comment: Você fez a pergunta mais não soube expressar o problema, reedite a pergunta de forma clara e objetiva.

Answer (score 2):

Quando for realizar uma pergunta no Stack Overflow, tente sempre referenciar os resources (javascript, css ou imagens) através de um [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) para facilitar a reprodução do erro.

Outra opção é utilizar algum site de `code playground`, como o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ou [CodePen](http://codepen.io/).

Em relação ao seu código, é importante ressaltar que a tag `input` não deve ser fechada, de acordo com a especificação disponível em [HTML 5.1#the-input-element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-input-element).

Tentei reproduzir o seu problema utilizando o código abaixo, no entanto, todos os elementos foram renderizados conforme o esperado. É provável que o problema seja o seu arquivo `style.css`, mas a gente não vai conseguir ter certeza até você compartilhar o conteúdo do mesmo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Troca Games - Games com economia</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="padding:15px; text-align:center">

    <form method="post" name="fm_login" class="login" data-transition="slide">
      <input name="usuario_usu" type="text" placeholder="Usuário">
      <input name="senha_usu" type="password" placeholder="Senha">
      <input type="submit" name="bt_login" value="Entrar">
    </form>

    <p style="font-size:20px">Não possui conta? <a href="#">Cadastre-se!</a>
    </p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vale ressaltar que o importante é fazer um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) com ***todo o código relevante incluido aqui na pergunta/resposta*** (exceto dependencias como jQuery, jQuery-mobile, etc) -em poucos casos o JSFiddle ou CodePen são necessários, é preferível o Stack Snippet como está aqui na resposta.